# Does size of two images being compared matter if md5 comparison is done?

Tags: image-processing, md5, image-comparison

I have two compare two images usinf md5 digest comparison. If the size of the two images is different will it matter?

Answer (score 2):

If the size is different, the content is different. Yes.

MD5 doesn't care about the meaning of the data (it can be a photo, a text, or anything represented in bytes).

[MD5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5)

Comment: This is right, but author maybe thought about comparing two images which one is the resized version of the second one. And it that case, answer is the same - it matters.